# Error when I open the terminal: `bash: /opt/ros/jage/setup.bash: No such file or directory`

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've try reinstall my ROS but after that when i reopen my terminal it will show me :

bash: /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory

And also during the Environment setup step when i type in " source ~/.bashrc "  it shows " bash: /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory "

any one know how to solve this problem? thank yo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229202/error-when-i-open-the-terminal:-%60bash:-/opt/ros/jage/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory%60/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-16**:
Which ROS-Distro did you install? The title says `hydro`,  the question `jade`. You cannot install them on the same system.

Also, if you tried reinstalling it and this file is not there, there has ben a problem with the reinstall. Where there any errors when you did `sudo apt-get install ros-<XY>`?

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-03-16**:
Sry, the title should be jage, is not hydro. and im installing indigo.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-16**:
Then please edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error means that your `.bashrc` still contains the following line

```
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
```

which, according to your question and the comments, you have uninstalled by now.
Simply remove this line in the `.bashrc`!

Above, you have been talking about reinstall ROS. If you uninstalled ROS Jade and now installed ROS Indigo, this error is obvious. For Indigo, you need to source `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0